# How to use jQuery and not $ as global for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

is what I did

```
$('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

Background for this question in the example showed is a Mix up one time is jQuery used the other time $ is used I will put the correct solution here

```
    jQuery('input').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
        }
    });
```

Method to scope $ directly

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.

  $('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Datepicker is capitalized in your first code, but not your second.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  If the bottom one is what you wanted, you could have just copy/pasted it

Comment: Well, `jQuery(function ('input').Datepicker({` is just a syntax error. What do you want to do? Wrap the second snippet in a [ready call](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap existing code into local scope without rewrite it!

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.

  $('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have used the "function" keyword there. You should have simply replaces the $ with "jQuery":

```
jQuery('input').datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/9knyT/

```
jQuery('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [array.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap it like so

```
$(function () {
    $('input').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [array.indexOf(string) == -1]
        }
    });
});
```